# .Net 6: WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated failing with DirectoryNotFound error

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, impersonation

I am facing a problem when using `WindowsIdentity.RunImpersonated`.
I am running an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API as self-hosted (`.exe`) and using `HTTP.Sys` as host (instead of Kestrel). I am impersonating a user before making a HTTP call to another Web API from within this Web API.

Currently logged on user in this Windows 10 box is a domain user who is part of local admin group. The user I am impersonating is the same (currently logged on user).

**When running the Web API by double clicking on it**

Inside this impersonation, while calling `HostBuilder.Build()`, the call is failing with an error

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException

The path in the exception is of the folder from where this Web API process is running. I checked in the .NET Core code and it is failing in

```
new PhysicalFileProvider(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath);
```

**When running web API by right click on exe and "Run as admin"**

No issues, HTTP call goes to other Web API and proper response is returned.

Even though I am logged on in this Windows machine with Admin privileges, still I have to run the Web API process explicitly as "Run as Admin" to make things work. This is what I am not getting.

Could someone please help here?

Comment: I think you can have a try the following answer:https://superuser.com/a/797557